# determine the default object type for the user model when you have multiple types from the same model

Tags: django, python-3.x, graphene-python

I create 2 objectTypes from the user model:

```
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):

    # ...

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
```

and

```
class TopRankedUsersType(DjangoObjectType):
    posts_count = graphene.Int()
    replies_count = graphene.Int()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        only_fields = ['id', 'username', 'photo', 'date_joined', 'points']
```

everything works fine, but I noticed that the default type to represent a user type is `TopRankedUsersType` instead of `UserType`

django / graghQl API

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue.  It seems to be related to the order that graphene loads all of objects related to the schema when Django starts up.  I realize this is an unsatisfactory answer, but you can probably change the default type by re-ordering `UserType` and `TopRankedUsersType`, presuming that they are both defined in the same file.

Comment: So the return type _isn't_ defined behavior, then? Is that by graphql specification, a bug in graphene-django? graphene? Any further context from any of the issue trackers?

Comment: As of 2018 when I discovered this, it seemed to be undocumented behavior in  graphene-django -- I have no idea what has changed since.  It would be better if the default objects could be set explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following from graphene doc: https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/objecttypes/#changing-the-name

Changing the name

By default the type name in the GraphQL schema will be the same as the class name that defines the ObjectType. This can be changed by setting the name property on the Meta class:

```
class MyGraphQlSong(graphene.ObjectType):
    class Meta:
        name = 'Song'
```

Comment: Thank you.  Maybe for plain graphene. Does this approach consider graphene-django?